# Is there a hidden condition in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I went through a FAQ on a website regarding an offer where it mentioned customers using a particular credit card can get a 10% discount. The minimum limit to get the discount is Rs. 6000.

> **1. What is the offer?**
>
> Get 10% cashback on the site (website and mobile) and 15% cashback on
> the app on successful single transaction net of refunds on purchases
> of Rs. 6000 and above from 1st to 5th Oct 2016. Cancelled items/orders
> will not be eligible for cashback. Additionally get 5% Cashback (in
> the form of reward points) on XXX Bank Debit cards, max up to Rs.
> 500.Detailed T&C for extra 5% cashback here < link >
>
> **4. What is the minimum transaction size for the cashback for the duration of the event (1st to 5th Oct '16)?**
>
> The minimum transaction size for the cashback duration is Rs. 6000 in a single transaction net of refunds and cancellations.

Here when they say "single transaction", I think they mean the offer is not applicable if you make more than one transaction that makes Rs. 6000.

That's not a problem, but could anybody tell me if it also means that the offer is valid only on "one" transaction (and it is not applicable if you try to make more than one transaction)?

Please note that I am not asking a business related question. I just had a debate with my brother and there were some silly arguments. I am just trying to know if the offer page has all details and request the company to update their page.

Thank you!

Comment: IMHO it could be read either way. But since you can easily combine two Rs. 6000 transactions into a single  Rs. 12000 transaction, it's more likely that there is no restriction to one transaction only.

Comment: It might be better to ask this in the [Money](http://money.stackexchange.com/) community.  You might get a clearer explanation of the terms there.

Comment: @michael-hor257k

> IMHO it could be read either way. But since you can easily combine two Rs. 6000 transactions into a single Rs. 12000 transaction, it's more likely that there is no restriction to one transaction only.


 >>> I thought the same but there was a little argument on this and I failed to prove

Comment: @Pete I will do that but I am not sure if that is a right platform as this is a language interpretation thing.

Comment: It is clear that there is no cashback for transactions under Rs 6000, even if the  total of such transaction exceeds Rs 6000. Other transactions over RS 6000 are eligible for Cashback. Depending on the interpretation, it may apply to all these transactions  or only to the first one (or the highest one?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site mentions two conditions which can be summarised as

> - successful single transaction of R6000
> - minimum transaction size is R6000 in a single transaction

Those are not incompatible.

One transaction of at least R6000 is eligible for the offer while it's running, but not transactions of less than that amount, even if they add up to R6000 or more.

The offer **might** be valid for more than transaction of at least R6000 because it mentions *purchases* in the plural, but that's not clear. It may well be a one-off cashback offer.

Had the ad said "**each** successful single transaction" or "successful single transaction**s**" that would have been clear: that would allow more than one, but would not allow aggregating transactions. It would also have been clear if it had said "**a** successful single transaction": that would definitely allow only one.

I fear the only people who will be able to answer this definitively are the people who made the offer.